# Finding mean from group by and displaying all information

Tags: python, count, pandas-groupby, mean

i have this data frame.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'userId': [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4],
                   'movieId': [500,600,700,1100,1200,600,600,1900],  
                   'ratings': [3.5,4.5,2.0,5.0,4.0,4.5,5.0,3.5]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'userId':[1,1,2,3,4,5],
                    'movieId':[500,600,1100,800,900,600],
                    'tag':['Highly quotable','Boxing story','MMA','Tom Hardy','Fun','long movie']})


frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames, sort = False)
result

  userId movieId ratings tag
0   1    500     3.5    NaN
1   1   600      4.5    NaN
2   1   700      2.0    NaN
3   2   1100     5.0    NaN
4   2   1200     4.0    NaN
5   3   600      4.5    NaN
6   4   600      5.0    NaN
7   4   1900     3.5    NaN
0   1   500      NaN    Highly quotable
1   1   600      NaN    Boxing story
2   2   1100     NaN    MMA
3   3   800      NaN    Tom Hardy
4   4   900      NaN    Fun
5   5   600      NaN    long movie
```

I am trying to groupby `movieId`. What i want is to count the number of occurrence for each movie.If count is 2 or more than 2 it should take the mean of `ratings` for this scenario and display all the information.
I have tried this but it is giving error. `KeyError: 'ratings'`.

Here is the code

```
group = result.groupby('movieId')['movieId'].count().reset_index(name="count")
agg = group['ratings'].mean().reset_index(name="mean")
agg
#right code here
```

Comment: Hi. So you want to see a new Data Frame with the fields movieId, tag and the mean of the rates?

Comment: yes with field movieId, tag, mean, count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll propose something different. I'll not use `concat`, instead I'll use `pd.merge`

Check this out:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'userId': [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4],
                   'movieId': [500,600,700,1100,1200,600,600,1900],
                   'ratings': [3.5,4.5,2.0,5.0,4.0,4.5,5.0,3.5]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'userId':[1,1,2,3,4,5],
                    'movieId':[500,600,1100,800,900,600],
                    'tag':['Highly quotable','Boxing story','MMA','Tom Hardy','Fun','long movie']})

# Merging df1 and df2, now you'll not have unnecessary NaN Values
result = df1.merge(df2[['movieId', 'tag']], on='movieId', how='left')

# Grouping by using two tipes of output with agg
result.groupby(by=['movieId', 'tag'], as_index=False).agg({'ratings': ['count', 'mean']})
```

The output will be:

```
  movieId              tag ratings          
                             count      mean
0     500  Highly quotable       1  3.500000
1     600     Boxing story       3  4.666667
2     600       long movie       3  4.666667
3    1100              MMA       1  5.000000
```

Hope it works for you

**Edit**

As you asked in the comments, if you want to filter the data frame, you can simply run the code bellow:

```
# Removing multiindex columns (just to be easier for you)
result = result.droplevel(0, axis=1)
result.columns = ['userId', 'movieId', 'ratings_count', 'ratings_mean']

# Filtering
result = result[result['ratings_count'] >= 2]
result = result[result['ratings_mean'] >= 3]
```

There is better ways to do this, but I'm assuming that you don't know yet how to work with Pandas MultiIndex, so I did a simple solution.

Comment: How can i display rows only where count is >=2 and mean >=3.